# I had hoped that I would see you the other day but I fell ill

Tags: conditional-constructions

Is this sentence correct or should we use                          either 'would have seen you' or 'I hoped'

Comment: It looks good to me the way it is.  *I had hoped* because this is before something else (before I fell ill).  *that I would see you* because at the time that I was hoping, the seeing was in the future.

Comment: It sounds good to me too.  There are many shorter/simpler versions that you will hear spoken (and sometimes written) but they are not quite as good grammatically or semantically.  We only use them because they are easier to say.

Comment: "that I would" is unnecessarily clunky.  You could say, "I had hoped to see you the other day, but I was sick."  "Fell ill" isn't a commonly used expression in everyday speech, at least in American English.

Comment: This is not a conditional construction.

Answer (score -1):

I would say "I hoped we would see each other the other day, but I fell ill/got sick and couldn't make it [to the event/meeting place/etc]".

But "had hoped" is fine too, but simple constructions should be preferred when the amount of information being conveyed is the same either way.